# Regex to split string on comma ",", but only if comma is not in between digits

Tags: python, regex, string

How could I split this given string into separate words -

Given string s = "Consumer notes, State Consumer Forum, Rs.50,000 penatly against ICICI,Andhra Pradesh"

I want the result to be = ["Consumer notes", "State Consumer Forum", "Rs.50,000 penatly against ICICI", "Andhra Pradesh"]

I am a newbie in regex and am not able to write regex for this.

Currently I am doing this

```
s = "Consumer notes, State Consumer Forum, Rs.50,000 penatly against ICICI,Andhra Pradesh"
result = set(w for w in s.split(r','))
print result

result:- 
set(['Andhra Pradesh', ' Rs.50', 'Consumer notes', '000 penatly against ICICI', ' State Consumer Forum'])
```

This gives me 5 words as it also splits the number Rs 50,000 into 2 parts. And I do not want this split. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6):

```
In [1]: s = "Consumer notes, State Consumer Forum, Rs.50,000 penatly against ICICI,Andhra Pradesh"

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.split(r'(?<!\d),(?!\d)',s)
Out[3]: 
['Consumer notes',
 ' State Consumer Forum',
 ' Rs.50,000 penatly against ICICI',
 'Andhra Pradesh']
```

you can use `re.split(r'(?<!\d),\s*(?!\d)',s)` to remove the spaces after `,` too.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can u give me some good references, so that I can understand your answer and write such regex in future. Can I also somehow remove the spaces which are coming in the starting. I know, I can use strip(). Any other way?

Comment: @mridul https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html is very good reference I think. What I used in the answer: negative look behind and negative look ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
(?<!\d),|,(?!\d)
```

Or

```
,(?!(?<=\d.)\d)
```

See the [regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/dWjXrN/1) demo and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dWjXrN/2/).

**Details**

- `(?<!\d),` - a comma not immediately preceded with a digit
- `|` - or
- `,(?!\d)` - a comma not immediately followed with a digit

This pattern is not that efficient because of 1) alternation and 2) lookbehind used at the start of the pattern making the regex engine check each position in the string.

- `,` - a comma that is...
- `(?!(?<=\d.)\d)` - not immediately followed with a digit (see `(?!...\d)`) that is immediately preceded with a digit and any one char (it is a comma in fact, so `.` and `,` here would work the same).

The second pattern is much more efficient as the regex engine only needs to test the commas in the text.